# toURI method of File transform space character into %20

Tags: java, uri

toURI method of File transform space character into %20

On windows XP with Java 6

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    File f = new File("C:\\My dir\\test.txt");
    URI uri = f.toURI();

    System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
    System.out.println(uri);
}
```

---

C:\My dir\test.txt
file:/C:/My%20dir/test.txt

Comment: And rightfully so. Where's your question?

Answer (score 1):

This is because URLs may not contains Space characters, as specified by [RFC2396](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt)!

Comment: piero, what was your solution?